# concatenate 3 dataframes changes column types of original

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 3 dataframes that I want to combine into a single dataframe. Before I do the concatenation, the columns in the first dataframe are series objects. But after I concatenate them, the columns that came from the original dataframe are now themselves DataFrames, rather than Series:

```
type(combined_data['text'])
pandas.core.series.Series
# Append to the combined_data set as new columns 
combined_data = pd.concat([combined_data, word_counts_df, keyword_counts_df], axis=1)
# Append to the combined_data set as new columns 
combined_data = pd.concat([combined_data, word_counts_df, keyword_counts_df], axis=1)
type(combined_data['text'])
pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
```

How do I combine the three dataframes WITHOUT changing the columns of the original from Series?

Comment: Check your word_counts_df and keyword_counts_df do they have column type dataframe ?

Comment: The columns in word_counts_df and keyword_counts_df are Series

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `combined_data` has multiple columns named "text".

`combined_data['text']` is returning all of these columns hence it is a `DataFrame`, not a `Series`.

Comment: You're right! Turns out that "text" was one of the words that appeared within the text strings I was separating into word counts, so word_counts_df had a "text" column, as did the original combined_data, as it had the text strings I was parsing into words (hadn't deleted that field yet).  Strange thing was that everything worked fine with two columns with the same name, until I went to try to do a str operation, which is when the error told me I was operating on a dataframe!.

Comment: I'm doing NLP, and there are over 3,000 columns, so until you pointed me in that direction, I hadn't reviewed all columns. Once you did, of course, it was easy to check.